# How to detect certain characters and wrap them with another string?

Tags: php

I have a question regarding the html string in php

I want to detect if the string contains `<tbody>` and if so, wrapped with `<table></table>` tags

My string will be something like:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

The problme is not every strings contain `<tbody>` and I need to detect if it has `<tbody>` tag

I just need to wrap the string with `<table>` so I can send the email to the client.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should avoid "dumb" string manipulation when working with structured data that comes serialized in a string. Instead, use `DOMDocument` to convert the string to a structured representation, `DOMXPath` to find the `<tbody>` nodes and wrap them in a `<table>` if their parent node is not one already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/DOMXPath).

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//tbody');

if ($result->length > 0) {
    //tbody found
}

?>
```

### [**See it live!**](http://codepad.org/z35gcqwC)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php), which allows to load, manipulate and save XML:

- http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php

Example usage [[source of sample]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php):

```
<?php
include 'example.php';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

$character = $xml->movie[0]->characters->addChild('character');
$character->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$character->addChild('actor', 'John Doe');

$rating = $xml->movie[0]->addChild('rating', 'PG');
$rating->addAttribute('type', 'mpaa');

echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

Based on this data:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
  <movies>
   <movie>
    <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
    <characters>
      <character>
        <name>Ms. Coder</name>
        <actor>Onlivia Actora</actor>
        </character>
      <character>
        <name>Mr. Coder</name>
        <actor>El Act&#211;r</actor>
      </character>
     </characters>
    </movie>
   <movies>
```

SimpleXML's [DOM methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) might be of interest too.

Comment: this is not a xml. It's just a simple html string returning from client side. +1 though