# How to manipulate strings in php

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a question regarding the DomDocument

In my previous questoin..
[How to detect certain characters and wrap them with another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433843/how-to-detect-certain-characters-and-wrap-them-with-another-string)

I can get the assign table to the string. However, there are some table cell that contains

```
<input type='text' value='input value'/>
```

so it's like

```
<td><input type='text' value='input value'/></td>
```

I want to remove the `input` tag but still display the `'input value'` in my cell as there is no input box. I need it because I need to display my string in my email.

I can't really do it in the client side.

Is there anyway to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you do it on the client side? This would be very easy with JavaScript/JQuery

Comment: @imulsion It sounds like this is for an email, so javascript would not be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the input value using [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) and an appropriate [`XPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$html = "<td><input type='text' value='input value'/></td>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$inputtags = $xpath->query('//input[@type="text"]');
foreach ($inputtags as $tag) {
    $value = $tag->getAttribute('value');
}
```

Output:

```
input value
```

Note: The XPath used here is just for demonstration purposes. There may be multiple elements with input type as `text` and it's probably a good idea to use a more solid XPath. However, this should get you started.

**[Demo!](http://codepad.org/CJQIMoHZ)**

Comment: Thanks Amal, how do I get the new $value save back to the original html? My html is not just as simple as here. I am thinking about saveHTML() but not sure where to begin. Thanks. +1

Comment: @FlyingCat: The above code allows you to extract the value of an input element from your HTML. The value will be stored in `$value` and you can output your HTML, like I've done in the demo. But, however, if you want to to do it the DOM way, then use [`replaceChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) and/or [`removeChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php‎)